# Acumatica - BQL - Using the generic type 'PX.Data.InnerJoin<Table,On>' requires 2 type arguments

Tags: acumatica

Code:

```
foreach (ARTran tran in PXSelect<ARTran, InnerJoin<ContractItem, 
On<ContractItem.contractItemID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>>,
Where<ARTran.tranType, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.docType>>,
And<ARTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>,
OrderBy<Asc<ARTran.tranType, Asc<ARTran.refNbr,
Asc<ARTran.lineNbr>>>>>>
.Select(Base, invoice.DocType, invoice.RefNbr))
```

When I try to publish, I get the following:

\App_RuntimeCode\ARReleaseProcess.cs(67): error CS0305: Using the generic type 'PX.Data.InnerJoin' requires 2 type arguments
\App_RuntimeCode\ARReleaseProcess.cs(67): error CS0305: Using the generic type 'PX.Data.InnerJoin' requires 2 type arguments

Answer (score 0):

The BQL query below should compile without any errors:

```
foreach (ARTran tran in PXSelectJoin<ARTran, 
    InnerJoin<ContractItem, 
        On<ContractItem.contractItemID, Equal<ARTran.inventoryID>>>, 
    Where<ARTran.tranType, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.docType>>, And<ARTran.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>, OrderBy<Asc<ARTran.tranType, Asc<ARTran.refNbr, Asc<ARTran.lineNbr>>>>>
    .Select(Base, invoice.DocType, invoice.RefNbr))
{
    ...
}
```